# Renaming a published task in a public extension

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

Given a public Azure DevOps extension, is there a way to change the task name (while keeping the id), that would maintain compatibility with pipelines that are referencing that task by its previous name?

The task.json schema does not mention support for aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not able to directly rename a public published task.

We could be able to [unpublish a task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/publish/overview?view=azure-devops#unpublish-an-extension) and re-publish item

- To unpublish, select the extension on your publisher page and choose
  Unpublish on the menu. Your extension is unpublished immediately from
  the Marketplace, and new users can't install it. Ratings and reviews
  for your extension stays intact.
- To offer your extension again in the Marketplace, choose Publish on
  the menu.

But not confirm if it will effect maintain compatibility with pipelines that are referencing that task by its previous name.

For this area, suggest you directly send questions about publishing items to the Visual Studio Marketplace to **vsmarketplace@microsoft.com**.